# How to pass variables from lm object to aes(x =, y = )?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

**Context:** I have a function that takes an object created with `stats::lm()` as its main argument. The goal of this function is to make ggplots with only this `lm` object. *Warning:* variables used in the model are NOT arguments of the function *i.e.* if the model is `lmobj <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)` then the function only takes `lmobj` as an argument. Indeed it is different from [question like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53696318/10264278). Moreover, I am not looking for "ggplot only" solutions that take the raw data and compute regression line and scatterplot (*e.g.* `ggplot2::geom_smooth(method = "lm")`).

**Problem:** `ggplot()` geom functions have a `x` and `y` argument that require unquoted variables (see [reference manual](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html)); how can I recover these from `lmobj`?

**Expected output:**

```r
library(ggplot2)
lmobj <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)
myfun <- function(.lm) {
  # make a scatterplot with .lm using ggplot
  ggplot(data = .lm[["model"]], aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point()
}
myfun(lmobj)
```

[image]

**Trials and errors**

I tried to grab an unquoted variable name from `lmobject` using `cat()`:

```
> cat(names(lmobj[["model"]][2]))
Petal.Length
```

But it creates an error:

```
> myfuntest <- function(.lm) {
+   # make a scatterplot with .lm using ggplot
+   ggplot(data = .lm[["model"]], aes(x = cat(names(.lm[["model"]][2])), 
+                                     y = cat(names(.lm[["model"]][1])))) +
+     geom_point()
+ }
> myfuntest(lmobj)
Petal.LengthPetal.WidthPetal.LengthPetal.WidthError: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
```

Comment: Aside: `cat` *prints* a string to the console, using it here is a complete no-go.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for your comment, I struggle to use these functions and related concepts such as quote/unquote, avaluated/non-evaluated, `!!`, `!!!`, `{`, *etc.* any tip is welcome :-) I also tried with `noquote()` but it failed with the error "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type noquote."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to evaluate first the arguments of `aes` as symbols and then call `aes` by wrapping it into a `do.call`

```r
myfun <- function(.lm) {
  ggplot(data = .lm[["model"]],
         do.call(aes, list(x = sym(names(.lm[["model"]])[2]),
                           y = sym(names(.lm[["model"]])[1])))) +
    geom_point()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this use of `do.call()` with `aes()`, I accept it as the answer because it allowed to do things such as `do.call(aes, list(x = .lm[["terms"]][[2]], y = .lm[["terms"]][[3]]))` that are usefull in other parts of the real function.

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
myfun <- function(model) {
  coefs <- names(model$model)
  ggplot(data = model$model) +
    aes(x = !! rlang::sym(coefs[1L]), y = !! rlang::sym(coefs[2L]))) +
    geom_point()
}
```

The relevant point here is that `aes` uses ‘rlang’s tidy evaluation and as such requires the arguments to be [injected via `!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html) as names.